# NSTokenField does not let me type other strings than tokenField:completionsForSubstring:... returns

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nstokenfield

My issue is that NSTokenField does not allow me to type any text I want, it's only allow me to type strings that are included in the NSArray that tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem: returns.

```
- (NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex      {
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AA", @"BB", @"CC", @"DD", nil];
}
```

My NSTokenField can only contain the above text-tokens.
If I type for example XXX it does not appeared and it cannot be added.

Why this happens since the documentation mentions "The user could enter a string that is not in the list of possible completions and that is also tokenized."

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for selectedItemIndex is 0 — the first item in your return list.

So you either need to set this to -1 in the case that substring isn't represented in your list (otherwise it will replace the text the user typed with the text of your first completion)

**or**

Only return things in the completion list which actually math the prefix the user typed. (This is often the correct user experience.)

```
- (NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex
{
   NSArray *completions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AA", @"BB", @"CC", @"DD", nil];
   NSMutableArray *filteredCompletions = [NSMutableArray array];

   [completions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       if ([[obj lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[substring lowercaseString]])
           [filteredCompletions addObject:obj];
   }];

   return filteredCompletions;
}
```