# How to pass indexofselecteditem in NSTokenField

Tags: cocoa, nstokenfield

My returns from tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem were clobbering my typed in items. This explains why: 
Reading this [NSTokenField does not let me type other strings than tokenField:completionsForSubstring:… returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697584/nstokenfield-does-not-let-me-type-other-strings-than-tokenfieldcompletionsforsu) answered most of my question.

In answering, Jim Correia said "So you either need to set this to -1 in the case that substring isn't represented in your list (otherwise it will replace the text the user typed with the text of your first completion)…"  In my case the specification is to return -1 but I don't see the way to do that? Maybe I'm just missing it somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading the docs, I finally worked through it. Added this to `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:`:

```
*selectedIndex = -1;
```

I missed the "return by-reference" bit.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you did here? I tried this (in Swift) but it doesn't work: http://d.pr/i/S8lz